# How to run a .out file and store the output in a .txt file inside a docker Container?

Tags: docker

I have built a docker Container named ubuntu-comp and run it with a volume by this command:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/vivek/PersonalSet/OJBh/Judge/folderrun/:/home/folderrun/ -d ubuntu-comp
```

This command runs successfully. Now I want to execute a command to run a file called c.out and store the output (STDOUT) in a text file called c.txt. Both files are stored in the volume directory.

Normally I'd use the command `/home/folderrun/c.out > /home/folderrun/c.txt`. This works fine if I run the Command in interactive mode, i.e. with the -it flag.

but when i run the following command:

```
sudo docker exec -it focused_wilbur /home/folderrun/c.out > /home/folderrun/c.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: /home/folderrun/c.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: See answer from Hans Kilian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by passing your command to /bin/sh like this

```
sudo docker exec -it focused_wilbur /bin/sh -c "/home/folderrun/c.out > /home/folderrun/c.txt"
```